# Neo4j dumps could be merged in single database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-desktop

I have two database instances: one remote and one local. I want to dump the local database and merge it with remote (structure of nodes & relationships are the same). How may I do it? Simple **neo4j-admin dump & load** will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the `dump` & `load` command.

To do what you want, you need to export your local database as CSVs and then make some `LOAD CSV` queries with `MERGE` command.

To export your database as CSVs, take a look at **[APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures)** with the export procedures : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_export_import